# How can I make an AppleScript activate upon logging in?

Tags: applescript, login

Is it possible to force an AppleScript to activate when I log in?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you save the Apple Script as an application, then go to  System Preferences -> Users -> Login Items, you can add the application there, and it will run on login.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

~/Library/LaunchAgents/login_test.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>login_test</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>osascript</string>
        <string>/Users/username/Desktop/test.scpt</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Script Timer](http://www.appsandmore.com/script_timer.htm) for this. It is $12, but it is a very useful little utility.